# Sencha Touch: How to submit long text/data through JSONP?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, jsonp

I want to send long text and save it in a database hosted online.
But I'm getting a 414 (Request-URI Too Large)

I'm stucked right now and cant find any solution.

As I know, JSON sends data through GET method. I was wondering if I can change it to POST method. Is it possible?

```
Ext.util.JSONP.request({
    url: 'http://host.com/folder/file.php?action=add',  
    callbackKey: 'callback',
    params: data,
    method: 'POST',
    success: function(response) {
        //do something
    },
    failure: function(response) {
        //do something
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**
I've tried to use a normal XHTMLREQUEST.
What I found out is, when I try to send without data, it is successful. But when I pass data, the error shows up again.

Comment: Why not? Try it. Dont forget replace $_GET to $_POST in php code

Comment: You can't use JSONP to do a POST. You could try cors, or possibly create a proxy on your own server, so you post to your server, then your server posts to the remote server.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli I want to run my app in both desktop browser and android phones. What proxy should I use?

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the servlet, another way to go is to implement CORS with Origin headers. After that, you can use the normal json request instead of jsonp.

Comment: I've tried this but it showed me this error: **Origin localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.** I dont know why I am having this error, since I already used CORS in my server: `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With'); header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');`